# Quasi-compact surjective morphism of smooth k-schemes is flat

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra

I have precedently posted the same question on Math.Stackexchange (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4277856/quasi-compact-surjective-morphism-of-smooth-k-schemes-is-flat), but to no avail; I hope this is not too low-level for this site.

In the article "The Greenberg functor revisited'' (https://doi.org/10.1007/s40879-017-0210-0) by Bertapelle and González-Avilés, one can read, before the statement of Theorem A.12, that a given morphism, call it $f\colon X\to Y$, "is a quasi-compact [even affine] and surjective morphism of smooth $k$-schemes [$k$ is a field] and therefore faithfully flat and locally of finite presentation.''  This might be trivial, but I have no idea how to prove flatness: the most general result of this kind which I have been able to find in the literature is EGA IV.15.4.2, which however requires one of the following conditions (I am keeping the same notation as in EGA), none of which I am able to deduce from the information above:

- $f$ is universally open;
- for any $x\in X$, $f$ is open at the generic points of the irreducible components of $X_{f(x)}$ containing $x$;
- for any $x\in X$, $\dim\mathcal{O}_{X,x}=\dim\mathcal{O}_{f(x)}+\dim(\mathcal{O}_{X,x}\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{f(x)}}\kappa(f(x)))$

I would be grateful for an explanation of why $f$ is flat.

Comment: You have left out essential information about the morphism in that article.  They appear to be considering a "change-of-rings" morphism associated to a local homomorphism between discrete valuation rings.  Obviously a local homomorphism between discrete valuation rings is flat if and only if it is an injective ring homomorphism.

Comment: @Jason Starr Sorry, but I do not get your objection: if I write "$f$ is flat since it satisfies property P", then either P implies flatness or it does not and my argument is wrong, irregardless of whether $f$ is flat for other reasons. Also, notice that $f$ is not a morphism between spectra of discrete valuation rings, but between schemes over a field.

Comment: If you take a fragment of a mathematical argument out of context, then you are misleading MO users.  The authors do not say that every morphism satisfying those properties is flat.  They say that one particular morphism, that happens to also satisfy additional properties, is flat.  There is a big difference.

Comment: @Jason Starr I hope I am not sounding polemic, but I disagree with you: I now see what you mean, but I do not agree with your interpretation of their sentence. With regard to the misleading accusation: if apologise I have mislead anyone; also notice that I did add some additional properties of such morphism which I thought might be relevant (affineness); of course I might have missed some others.

Comment: My understanding of the non-paywall text is that the authors prove flatness of the change-of-rings morphism of Greenberg spaces by applying the valuative criterion of flatness to the associated natural transformation of functors represented by the Greenberg spaces of $\mathfrak{R}'/k$, respectively $\mathfrak{R}/k$.  They, in fact, conclude that the natural transformation is a torsor for a vector bundle group scheme except for checking that the flat morphism is fpqc.  But then they note that the map is quasi-compact and surjective, hence fpqc, and it is even fppf.

Comment: @Jason Starr Thank you for pointing this out; none of this features in the paywalled text. However, I am a bit confused about the argument in the ArXiv version: it relies on Corollary 11.8 (of the ArXiv version; it does not appear in the published one), in whose proof a lemma which is valid only for a morphism of group schemes is applied to the change of ring morphism between two schemes which are Greenberg spaces of a smooth scheme, and need not be group schemes in general (I think). Maybe I am missing something trivial here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest blowup morphism $\mathrm{Bl}_0(\mathbb{A}^2) \to \mathbb{A}^2$ (with center at a point) is not flat.

EDIT. Here is an example with affine morphism. Let
$$
X = \{ x_1y_1 + x_2y_2 + x_3y_3 = 0 \} \subset \mathbb{A}^4_{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4} \times \mathbb{A}^4_{y_1,y_2,y_3}
$$
and let $f \colon X \to \mathbb{A}^3$ be the projection to the second factor. This example, however, is **singular** at the point $(0,0)$.

EDIT 2. Consider the variety
$$
\bar{X} = \{x_1y_1 + x_2y_2 + x_3y_3 = 0\} \subset
\mathbb{P}^2_{x_1:x_2:x_3} \times 
\mathbb{A}^3_{y_1,y_2,y_3}.
$$
It is smooth, because the projection to $\mathbb{P}^2$ is a fibration with fiber $\mathbb{A}^2$. On the other hand, the projection $\bar{f} \colon \bar{X} \to \mathbb{A}^3$ is not flat, because the dimension of the fiber jumps at $0$.

Now let
$$
X = \bar{X} \cap 
((\mathbb{P}^2 \setminus C) \times \mathbb{A}^3),
$$
where $C$ is a smooth conic. Then

1. $X$ is smooth, because it is open in $\bar{X}$;
2. $X$ is affine over $\mathbb{A}^3$ because $\mathbb{P}^2 \setminus C$ is affine,
3. the map $f \colon X \to \mathbb{A}^3$ is surjective, because the smooth conic $C$ cannot contain a fiber of $\bar{f}$ (a line or the plane),
4. the map $f$ is not flat, because the dimension of the fiber still jumps at $0$.

Comment: I could not find a Theorem A.12 in the reference.

Comment: Sasha: Thank you very much for your answer; do you know any counterexamples in the case the morphism is even affine?

Comment: @Laurent Moret-Bailly: Are you looking at the ArXiv version or at the published version? The two differ considerably; in the ArXiv version, the result I was referring to is Theorem 12.13.

Comment: @Vanni I can't find the sentence "is a quasi-compact [even affine] and surjective morphism of smooth -schemes [ is a field] and therefore faithfully flat and locally of finite presentation" in the arXiv version.

Comment: @Ariyan Javanpeykar The version I am referring to is the published one; you can access the relevant part following the link I provided (theorem A.12 is in Appendix B, which can be read online also without accessing the full document); the comments between square brackets are mine.

Comment: @Vanni: I added to the answer an example of non-flat affine morphism.

Comment: But your $X$ is singular at $(0,0)$.

Comment: @abx: thanks for pointing this! I will modify my example later.

Comment: @abx: please, have a look at the new example.

Comment: @Sasha: Very good!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the version that we would like people to read (and hopefully check for more mistakes, if any remain) is the Arxiv version of our paper. We worked on that for 4 years and with great care. Unfortunately, we were asked to reduce the length of our paper significantly as a precondition for publication, or that's my recollection, anyway. The result of this abridgement is not the happiest it could have been; the published version may well be harder to follow than the preprint version. Anyway, as stated above, we worked on our paper with great care, but we still made a (thankfully inconsequential) mistake (see below). When writing our original argument, we overlooked the fact that the scheme $X$ below is not necessarily a *group* scheme, so that an additional argument is needed to fill the gap. Here it is (all references are to the Arxiv version):

In Corollary 11.8  we state that the change of rings morphism is
faithfully flat if $Z$ is smooth over $\mathfrak R$. The proof there
is incomplete since Lemma 2.52 holds for morphism of smooth *group* schemes.
The required additional arguments for proving flatness are the following:

We may work locally on $Z$ and assume that $Z$ is etale over an
affine space $\mathbb A^n_{\mathfrak R}$. By Proposition 9.19, it suffices to consider the case
$Z=\mathbb A^n_{\mathfrak R}$. The latter scheme can be endowed with the usual additive group scheme structure, whence the change of rings morphism is a morphism of $k$-group schemes (see the lines below diagram (9.15)). We can now apply  Lemma 2.52 to complete the proof.

Many thanks to I.Vanni for calling our attention to this problem!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I planned to rectify my question and include some of this information (which had been kindly communicated to me by Alessandra Bertapelle), but having been very busy I have not managed to do so quickly enough; I apologise for this.

Comment: Dear Vanni, many thanks for your interest in our work. Certainly no apology is needed. We wrote this paper to understand Greenberg's important ideas and also as a service to the mathematical community. We can all make mistakes (the long list of mathematicians that have published erroneous statements include one called Poincare and another one called Grothendieck). The important thing is to identify them as quickly as possible and correct them, if possible, or modify the relevant statement if necessary. Hey, I found another name to add to the list alluded to above. A guy named Einstein.